# Script Onclick makes jscript error

Tags: javascript, php

I have two scripts on my site makes a jscript error with the Onclick and Style null. How can i solve this?

1.

```
<script>
document.getElementById("chooser-image").onclick = function () {
    Dropbox.choose({
        linkType: "direct",
        extensions: ['.pdf', '.jpg', '.zip'],
        success: function(files) {
            var linkTag = document.getElementById('link');
            linkTag.href = files[0].link;
            linkTag.textContent = files[0].link;
        }
    });
};
```

Error :
TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
http://www.domain.dk/kontakt-os:1019

---

2.

```
<!-- LiveZilla Tracking Code (ALWAYS PLACE IN BODY ELEMENT) -->
<div id="livezilla_tracking" style="display:none"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.async=true;
script.type="text/javascript";
var src = "http://www.domain.dk/chat/server.php?a=fd125&request=track&output=jcrpt&intgroup=U3VwcG9ydA__&intid=cm9ubmk_&pref=dXNlcg__&hg=Pw__&hcgs=MQ__&htgs=MQ__&ovlp=MjI_&ovlc=IzczYmUyOA__&ovlct=I2ZmZmZmZg__&ovlml=Ng__&ovlt=Q2hhdCBvbmxpbmU_&ovloo=MQ__&eca=MQ__&ecw=MjUw&ech=OTU_&ecmb=Mjk_&echt=U3DDuHJnc23DpWw,&echst=Q2hhdCBtZWQgb3MgbnU_&ecoht=UXVlc3Rpb25zPw__&ecohst=UGxlYXNlIGxlYXZlIGEgbWVzc2FnZQ__&ecfs=I0YwRkZENQ__&ecfe=I0QzRjI5OQ__&echc=IzZFQTMwQw__&ecslw=Mg__&ecsgs=IzY1OUYyQQ__&ecsge=IzY1OUYyQQ__&nse="+Math.random();
setTimeout("script.src=src;document.getElementById('livezilla_tracking').appendChild(script)",1);
</script>
<noscript>
    <h1><img src="http://www.print.dk/chat/server.php?a=fd125&amp;request=track&amp;output=nojcrpt&amp;intgroup=U3VwcG9ydA__&amp;intid=cm9ubmk_&amp;pref=dXNlcg__&amp;hg=Pw__&amp;hcgs=MQ__&amp;htgs=MQ__" width="0" height="0" style="visibility:hidden;" alt=""></h1>
</noscript><!-- http://www.LiveZilla.net Tracking Code -->
```

Error :
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
http://www.domain.dk/chat/templates/overlays/chat/jscript/jsextern.js:450&host=www.print.dk

Comment: First error means there is no element in your DOM with ID 'chooser-image' - or if there is, the script is running before the DOM has loaded or before the element has been inserted into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Your first script should be before you close `</body>`, or after `<div id="chooser-image" />` or inside `document.onload = function{}`. For second code snippet: it should be inside the `<body>`, **not** in between `<head>` tags. Your error says that `<div id="livezilla_tracking" />` does not exist at all.

Comment: Both scripts are just before body close. I dont have a <div id="chooser-image" />

Comment: Well that's your first error, insert `chooser-image` div before the script. Think like second error is not connected to livezilla-tracking at all, you must have other scripts on page?